# How to make Outlook 2013 Calendar reminders stay on top in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook-2013, reminder

This was asked/answered 4 years ago for Windows 7.  I'm hoping there's an answer that doesn't require editing code or buying 3rd-party software.

Comment: I'm not on my windows box right now, so I can't test it, but did you try AutoHotKey and a simple one-liner like "^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A"? You don't have to use a hotkey and manually trigger it each time the windows opens, you can just use the window title for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution that meets your criteria. Only Microsoft can fix and our screams land on deaf Microsoft ears.